# Properties and geometrical interpretations of a specific planar vector law.

Tags: reference-request, vectors, binary-operations, plane-geometry

***Genesis of the following thoughts.***

One usually define the following internal composition law on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$+:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\
((a,b),(c,d))&\mapsto&(a+b,c+d)
\end{array}\right..$$
One has the handy:

> **Geometrical interpretation 1.** Let $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}$ is the direct diagonal of the oriented-parallelogram formed by the vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Moreover, the interest of $+$ is strengthened by the following algebraic:

> **Fact 1.** $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ is an abelian group.

Let me try to explain what is frustrating me about $+$. Let $i\in\{1,2\}$, the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ coordinates of $\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}$ is only dependent upon the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ coordinates of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ which appears to be the first natural idea one can have to define a planar vector law. However, there is no apparent good reason for $+$ to be the sole natural planar vector law and this is how I motivated myself to construct $\rtimes:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the $i^{\textrm{th}}$ coordinates of $\mathbf{u}\rtimes\mathbf{v}$ is dependent upon both coordinates of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ with the restriction that $\rtimes$ has sweet geometrical interpretations. I don't mind losing some algebraic properties even if it will be better if an algebraic-friendly law arises.

---

***An attempt to define $\rtimes$ and some partial results.***

Let define the following internal composition law on $\mathbb{R}^2$: 
$$\rtimes:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\
((a,b),(c,d))&\mapsto&(a+bc,b+ad)
\end{array}\right..$$
My thought here is to weight $+$ with the *relevant* coordinates of $\mathbf{u}$ or $\mathbf{v}$. From there, it is relevant to introduce this other internal composition law on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\otimes:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^ 2\\
((a,b),(c,d))&\mapsto&(bc,ad)
\end{array}\right..$$

> **Observation 1.** Let $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, one has $\mathbf{u}\rtimes\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$.

Let us focus our attention on $\otimes$ and make the following:

> **Observation 2.** Let $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbf{v}\otimes\mathbf{u}$ is the axially symmetric about the first bisector of $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$.

One derives the following:

> **Fact 2.** $\rtimes$ is non-commutative.

Before making some geometric observations, let us make some algebraic remarks:

> **Proposition 2.**
>
> - $(0,0)$ is the right identity element for $\rtimes$.
> - Let $\mathbf{u}:=(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, there exists a unique ${\mathbf{u}_{r}}^{-1}\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that: $$\mathbf{u}\rtimes{\mathbf{u}_{r}}^{-1}=(0,0).$$ One has $\displaystyle{\mathbf{u}_{r}}^{-1}=-\left(\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{a}\right)$.

However, $\rtimes$ has a nasty left behaviour.

Let us now make the geometric remarks:

> **Observation 3.** Let $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> - The difference of the coordinates of $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$ is the area of the oriented-parallelogram formed by the vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.
> - If $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}\propto (1,-1)$, then $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v}$. Moreover, $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are anticolinear.

---

***Some interrogations.***

- $1.$ Is there some reference in the literature on defining such a planar vector law?
- $2.$ Is there a way to temper the nasty left behaviour of $\rtimes$?
- $3.$ Is there a geometrical interpretation of ${\mathbf{u}_r}^{-1}$?
- $4.$ Is the converse of the second point in observation $3.$ true?
- $5.$ Is there a stronger geometrical interpretation of $\otimes$ and can we derive from it a geometrical interpretation of $\rtimes$?

Any contribution or constructive remark will be greatly appreciated!

**Update 1.** I came up with the following results digging [hjhjhj57](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/150361/hjhjhj57)'s idea.

First, let define the following embedding of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$:
$$i:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^3\\
(a,b)&\mapsto&(a,b,0)
\end{array}\right.\textrm{ and }j:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^3\\
(a,b)&\mapsto&(0,a,b)
\end{array}\right..$$

> **Fact 3.** $i\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ is the plane $z=0$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $j\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ is the plane $x=0$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, let define the following projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$p:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^3&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\
(a,b,c)&\rightarrow&(a,b)
\end{array}\right.$$
One can interpret $p$ has the projection onto the plane $z=0$. Let define the following transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$\sigma:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2\\
(a,b)&\mapsto&(b,a)
\end{array}\right..$$
$\sigma$ is the axial symmetry about the first bissector *i.e.* $y=x$. From there, one can make the following:

> **Observation 4.** Let $(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, one has: $$\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}=p\left(i(\sigma(\mathbf{u})\right)\times j(\mathbf{v})).$$
>   In other words, $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$ is the projection onto $z=0$ of the cross-product of the axially symmetric about the first bissector of $\mathbf{u}$ seen into the plane $z=0$ with $\mathbf{v}$ seen into the plane $x=0$.

**Proof.** For all $\mathbf{u}:=(a,b),\mathbf{v}:=(c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, one has $\begin{pmatrix}b\\a\\0\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}bc\\ad\\-bd\end{pmatrix}.$ $\Box$

One can also make the following observation: $$\begin{pmatrix}b\\a\\d\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}bc\\ad\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
, which probably leads to another geometrical interpretation of $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$. The strong point of this last identidy is that while projecting the result onto the plane $z=0$ to recover $\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}$, one only loses a coordinate equal to $0$ and thus does not lose information. However, the embeddings of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ used are non-canonical and they are depends of the coordinates of $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

How can these observations be used to answer my interrogations?

Comment: When you define $u_r^{-1}$ you need to ask for $a$ and $b$ different from zero. This is different from $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. On the other hand, you could try to play around with the cross-product of two vectors and see how it relates to these functions you're defining.

Comment: Your first point is very right, I fixed this mistake! Besides, I thought using Hurwitz's theorem that one can only define a cross-product in dimension $0,1,3$ and $7$. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about cross-product in dimension 3, since you can always embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a vector subspace. The reason why it may be useful is that, as you may know, the length of the cross product of two vectors is precisely the (unsigned) area they span.

Comment: I see your point! This seems very interesting and seems likely to help me understanding better $\otimes$. I will dig this thought and if I find something relevant I will let you know by editing my question.

Comment: Cool! Let's hope it's a fruitful idea.